# How get alternate only g,v, and w with newtxmath?

Tags: times, newtxmath

I'm using newtxmath package and I wish only get open g, \varv and \varw without change 'y' in math mode. I know the varg and varvw options change all of them and only 'v' and 'w',respectively,  but not what I need. Is there a option or way to solve my problem?

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a minimal working example demonstrating the issue. Please also clarify which engine you are using for compilation and whether changing this is an option.

Answer (score 4):

Inside `newtxmath.sty` you'll find the lines

```
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\varg}{\mathord}{lettersA}{188} % was 49
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\vary}{\mathord}{lettersA}{189}  % was 50
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\varv}{\mathord}{lettersA}{190}  % was 51
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\varw}{\mathord}{lettersA}{191} % was 52
```

so to change only g, v, and w, just declare them as above.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newtxmath}

\DeclareMathSymbol{g}{\mathord}{lettersA}{188}
\DeclareMathSymbol{v}{\mathord}{lettersA}{190}
\DeclareMathSymbol{w}{\mathord}{lettersA}{191}

\begin{document}

$gyvw$

$\varg\vary\varv\varw$

\end{document}
```

[image: letters]